# What is the purpose of relative addresses in Passport application?

Tags: indian-citizens, passport

I am working in USA with H1B VISA. I am from India. Now I am applying passport renewal.

In the renewal application form, there is a section where I have to give 2 of my relatives/friends address who live India.

What is the purpose of this section and what Indian Government will do with these addresses?

Answer (score 1):

During the verification process the passport office might contact them to ensure that the details furnished by you are indeed correct and up to date.

In addition, these names / details will be kept on your file with the Ministry of External Affairs.